# Setting a canvases width toe the width of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs of a predefined width and height, established in the CSS. I want a canvas to fill these divs, but I also want it to dynamically change size based on the div's size. In my html, I establish the canvas in each div using

```
<canvas class="canvases" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

In the head of the document, I run the following function when the div is clicked

```
function establishCanvases() {
 canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvases');
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
     canvas[i].width = $(".projectContainer").css("width");
     alert (i + " " + $(".projectContainer").css("width"));
 }
}
```

The alert is there solely for debugging purposes—it's let me know that it is indeed grabbing the correct width of the projectContainer class. However, when I click the div to invoke the function, the canvas width is set to 0, rather than the value it finds at $(".projectContainer").css("width"). Why would this be?

As well, to avoid having to make a new thread for a simple question; how can I get the function to run automatically when loading the document, rather than on clicking the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code to add to resize event and to fire on page load:

```
var setCanvasSize = function(){
  canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvases');
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
     canvas[i].width = parseInt($(".projectContainer").css("width"));
     alert (i + " " + $(".projectContainer").css("width"));
   }
};

var timer;
//add to window resize event
$(window).resize(function(){
   clearTimeout(timer);
   setTimeout(setCanvasSize, 100);
});
//fire on page load
setCanvasSize();
```

The reason that the width isn't setting was that canvas takes an integer as a width value, while the jQuery.css("width") is returning as a string with "px" appended. A quick and dirty way to force it to just a number is by using `parseInt()`, but there are other ways available.

Comment: Ahh, I never thought of that, thanks a bunch! I haven't dealt with a self-invoking function before—since this is placed in the document head, it's not going to be constantly resizing the canvases to match the div, is it? How could I get it to do that?

Comment: Ah, you'll need to attach it to a resize function in order to have it fire as the browser resizes. I'll update my example.

Comment: @GtwoK updated the code with resize ( there is a debounce on the resize that isn't 100% necessary, but generally is considered a good practice ).